# Get the class attributes of specific I which have class "active"

Tags: jquery

My html code is this, i need to get all the class attributes of the active li.

```
 <ul class="daily">     
        <li class="day active temp_2">1</li>
        <li class="day temp_1">2</li>
        <li class="day temp_3">3</li>
        <li class="day temp_4">4</li>
    </ul
```

i have used this code but failed

```
jQuery('#daily > ul > li').hasClass('active').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
jQuery('ul.daily > li.active').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.daily li.active').attr('class');
```

`li.active` selector will bring all `li` having `active` class.

Answer (score 1):

`daily` is not id it is a class name

try this

```
$('.daily li.active').attr('class');
```

Comment: since .hasClass('active') returns a boolean attaching .attr('class') to it won't work.

$('.daily li.active').attr('class'); seems to be a better solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do this...

```
var allclasses = jQuery('.daily li.active')[0].className.split(/\s+/)
```